# How to override/ replace existing object

Tags: javascript, paperjs

Due demand, I give all the code in respect to `onmouseClick`:

First I import svg each in a new layer into canvas:

```
//imports svg from external js script
var svgimportSVG = function (elem,x) {

// creates a new layer for each imported svg
var layer = new Layer();
layer.name = "Layer" +x;
layer.activate();

// import here
rect = paper.project.importSVG(elem,function(item){
    console.log("Elem: " + elem);        
});
```

Then I build the "frame" as a path on bounds:

```
// build a frame
rect.data.showBounds = new Path.Rectangle({
    rectangle: rect.bounds,
    strokeColor: 'aqua'
});

return rect;
}
```

I want the effect that only the clicked element or the least imported element has a visible frame:

```
tool.onMouseDown = function(e) {
var hitResult = project.hitTest(e.point, hitOptions);
if(hitResult){
    var SVGGroup = searchSVGGroup(hitResult.item,"svg");
    var SVGLayer = searchSVGGroup(hitResult.item,"layer");

    // Layer of clicked object shall be in front or last element in project.layers

    console.log(SVGLayer.name);
    var IndexOfLayer = project.layers.indexOf(SVGLayer);
    project.layers.splice(IndexOfLayer,1);
    project.layers.push(SVGLayer);
    var LayersLengthnew = project.layers.length;

    //Clicked object can be influenced ouside paperscope 
    window.globals.extExportOnMouseClick(project.layers[LayersLengthnew -1].name);

    SVGGroup.data.showBounds = new Path.Rectangle({
        rectangle: rect.bounds,
        strokeColor: 'aqua'
    });

    // sent as old clicked object
    svgSetRemoveFrameofGroup(SVGGroup);
}
else{...}
}

//create an empty object that holds the last clicked object 
var svgFramedGroup = {};

var svgSetRemoveFrameofGroup = function(rect){

  var rectold = {};
  console.log("rect name: "+ rect.name); // gives correct name    
  if(svgFramedGroup.data){
    rectold = svgFramedGroup;
    console.log("rect old name: "+ rectold.name); // gives correct name
  }

  svgFramedGroup = rect;

  if(!svg_isEmpty(rectold)){
    //... showBounds should go to Garbage collector
    rectold = rectold.data.showBounds.remove();
  }

  return rectold;
}
```

But the further clicked element has still its bounds which is a path!?

Comment: Can you show more code. Both the DOM and the onMouseDown()

Comment: is remove a functionality provided by paperjs? I'm not sure how it would work... If you're just looking to remove a property/object would the `delete` operator work for you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: Yes, it is: http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#remove

Answer (score 1):

I answered you [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/paperjs/cGC-KLUMelQ) for the same question.

The only different thing is that here you're asking for a "frame" shown when an element is clicked and there you're asking for it to be hidden when element is clicked (which is what I did in my example).

But you should be able to get the logic anyway.